# has_one through has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello can please anyone help me with the associations? I have an article with ONE preview image and MANY article images.Images can be used to many articles. So my models are:

```
class Article 
  has_many :article_images
  has_many :main_images, :class_name => "Image", :through => :article_images
  has_one  :preview_image, :class_name => "Image", :through => :article_images
end

class ArticleImage
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :preview_image, :class_name => "Image", :foreign_key => :image_id, :conditions => ["images.itype = 'preview_image'"]
  belongs_to :main_image, :class_name => "Image", :foreign_key => :image_id, :conditions => ["images.itype = 'main_image'"]
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_images
  has_many :articles
end
```

The problem is that with this code I get the error :

```
ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have a has_one :through association 'Article#preview_image' where the :through association 'Article#article_images' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead
```

If I create into articles a new association for the preview_image like this :

```
has_one :article_image
has_one  :preview_image, :class_name => "Image", :through => :article_image
```

doesn't seem to work correctly.
Can someone please suggest me a solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I would make `preview` a column on the `article_images` table. Then do:

```
class Article 
  has_many :article_images
  has_one  :preview_image, :class_name => "ArticleImage", :conditions => {:preview => true}
end

class ArticleImage
  belongs_to :Article
end
```

Comment: Yes, that would work but I'd rather not change the db schema.I use the rails app only to read data from the db. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your "ArticleImage" doesn't seem right. It belongs both to a "preview image" and to a "main image", when it should have a single image there (of any type). The only way that model would make sense, is adding some constraint that one and only one of those two properties has a value and the other is null.

Also, do you have more properties in ArticleImage? Why make a :through association for the preview image? Why not make:

```
class Article 
  has_many :article_images
  has_many :main_images, :class_name => "Image", :through => :article_images
  belongs_to  :preview_image, :class_name => "Image"
end
```

And have in this class the foreign key of the one and only preview image?